# Webview not working if I am passing parameters to url in assets folder.?

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

I am working on an app where i need to pass parameters to url while loading html file in webview from assets folder. If I am passing parameters webview was not loading & If not it's working good. **The following code is working in 2.1 & 2.3 versions but coming to 4.0 version it's not working.**

code:

webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); //this is working

webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html?" + parameters); //this is not working
   //to pass parameters I am adding "?" at the end & it's not working.

Can anyone please help me with any alternative code for passing parameters to the following url.

Comment: Passing http parameters means you need to have a web server application that can actually process these parameters. In your case, you're telling the webview to load an html file. The `WebView` doesn't know how to handle these parameters

Comment: see my answer and try this i think it will help u dear..:)

Comment: @gunar that is what I am saying about. I need to pass parameters to html page. so here webview is unable to loading the following html file in assets folder with that parameters passed. Is there any alternative solution for this.

Comment: yes, have a javascript inside the html that is instructed to do what you're expected. Then once the page is loaded, call that function

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a JavaScript method to your HTML and pass the parameters in via that function after loading the page? Something like ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function receiveParameters(p) {
  // Do something with p
}
</script>

webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
webview.evaluateJavascript("receiveParameters(" + parameters + ");", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it...

```
String filePath = "/data/user/0/~/files/public";

//launchUrl = String.format("%s/index.html?id=test", filePath);
//-->
launchUrl = String.format("file://%s/index.html?id=test", filePath);

webview.loadUrl(launchUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shouldInterceptRequest` to remove the query before `assetLoader` seek for the file:

```kotlin
     webview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

            override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
                view: WebView,
                request: WebResourceRequest
            ): WebResourceResponse? {

                if (request.url.host == "appassets.androidplatform.net") {
                     // Do any logic you want to remove disturb parmeters
                    var url = request.url
                    if (request.url.queryParameterNames.contains("yourparam")) {
                        url = Uri.parse(request.url.toString().split("?")[0])
                    }
                    return assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(url)
                }
           }
     }
```

Now your html will be available to handle the parameters. But the assets loader do not care.